# Transform TFT to AMOLED

Tags: lcd, tft, oled, amoled

I was wondering if it is possible to transform a TFT LCD into an AMOLED as both are active matrixes.
The composition seems to be similar.

**AMOLED**

[image: AMOLED components]

**TFT (LCD)**

[image: LCD TFT components]

And if it wouldn't be possible, could I at least keep just the part that is very hard to manufacture (the TFT itself)? Maybe do the rest myself?

Comment: intriguing ... are you trying to do and why?

Comment: I recall AMOLEDs are much different with a microslice silicon layer.

Comment: LCD TFTs and AMOLED displays work in **very** different ways, their construction is also very different. The fact that they both use Thin Film Transistors (TFT) is irrelevant. It should be obvious that one cannot be converted into the other. Again you need to learn more basic stuff like I suggested before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) no.

B) they're not really similar.

C) the other parts are also very hard.